# Why is there an error when setting the value of "debugging" to "true" in android application?

Tags: android, debugging, android-manifest

Whenever I set the value of "debugging" to "true" in my android app, there is an error.
The description of the error is: "Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `android:debuggable="true"` from your manifest.

First, you probably don't need it. Even with Eclipse, normal IDE builds are automatically debuggable, as is any process on an emulator. A release build, on production hardware, would not be debuggable, which is what you want, for security reasons.

If you need more flexibility than that, and you are using Android Studio/Gradle for Android, set up custom build types in `build.gradle` to model your other scenarios. The default `debug` build type will make the app be debuggable; the default `release` build type would make your app not debuggable. Custom build types can use the `debuggable` statement to state what they should do:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('HelloConfig.keystore')
            keyAlias 'HelloConfig'
            storePassword 'laser.yams.heady.testy'
            keyPassword 'fw.stabs.steady.wool'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
          applicationIdSuffix ".d"
          versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        mezzanine.initWith(buildTypes.release)

        mezzanine {
            applicationIdSuffix ".mezz"
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I say that my `mezzanine` custom build type should be debuggable, via `debuggable true` in its definition.